# where to put -f tmux.conf on a script to initialize tmux session?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I have created a file to init my tmux session:

```
tmux new-session
tmux split-window
...other stuff...
tmux attach
```

my issue is, my tmux.conf file is NOT located at my $HOME (for some reasons not to be discussed here). So I don't know where should I pass the

```
-f tmux.conf
```

so it is used. Should it be in the new-session? in the attach? I have tried both but none seem to work.

thanks

Comment: you could also make a s-link under you home.

Comment: @Kent, I don't want to touch anything at ~/

Comment: another dirty solution is make an alias in your script ,e.g `mytmux -> tmux -f foo` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after attaching a session, you can explicitly source your `tmux.conf` file with command `source-file path`.

with `-f`, the file was loaded when the process started.

Comment: yes, I know about the source-file but I was looking for a way to embed the -f in the script somewhere. Can you elaborate on the -f? When is it when the process started?

Comment: if you want to use `-f file`, you have to add it to the first tmux command line, e.g. in your example the `tmux -f file new-session`.   before you run your script, you should make sure there is no tmux process (server) running. run a `tmux kill-server` first. @Persimmonium

Comment: -f is not working for me anywhere, so given that running source-file is a one time thing, ill accept this anwswer, if I get a better one for -f I'll change it

Comment: @Persimmonium I just gave it a test, create a script file as you posted, add `-f file` to the first `tmux line`, del the tmux server, run the script, the conf was loaded.

Comment: ok I'll test again tomorrow, but I could not get it to work. It is a bit hard to understand, for instance, just any call to tmux would work? So if I do: tmux kill-server; tmux -f confile has-session -t sess;  the call to has-session is the first one after the kill, should the conf file be picked up or it will be in certain commands only like new-session...@Kent